# Xamarin.Forms creating custom objects to display as a list

Tags: c#, android-custom-view, xamarin.forms

I'm fairly new to mobile development in C#, but I decided to dive into Xamarin.Forms to develop for the three major platforms at once. What I would like to do now is create a custom object that contains text, an image, and a button, and I would like to be able to create multiples of them depending on how many sets are present in my database. I aware of the ContentPage class and then saw that ContentView can only contain a single child element, so I'm not sure what type of class I would use in order to create a custom visual object. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ListView](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/) class ([API doc](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ListView)). It should do the trick. It's relatively straightforward to create a [DataTemplate](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.DataTemplate) with a [ViewCell](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ViewCell) that represents the UI for your collection of data objects, which you will then assign to the ListView's ItemsSource property. The result is a scrollable list that updates with your data source.

There are lots of benefits to using this component, including built-in [pull-to-refresh](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#pulltorefresh), template re-use, and [context actions](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#context).